# How can I make a request in React when a specific page is navigated away from or closed using React Router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-router, apollo

I have a React application using React Router v6 where I would like to call a GraphQL mutation (using Apollo Client) when a user leaves a specific page in the app either by clicking the browser's back button, navigating away from the page using in-app buttons (page unmounts), or closing the tab/browser.

Perhaps this isn't entirely possible in the way I want but also if it isn't possible with Apollo Client but is possible with a more typical request, that's fine.

Here are some of the things I have tried

**Calling it from the clean up function in the `useEffect` hook**

I expected this to work whenever the page unmounts but I was naive in understanding how React responds to events like closing a browser or tab as React does not become aware of this. It did work for browser back arrow use and react router navigation though, albeit not super reliably.

**visibilitychange event handler**

```
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    callMutation();
};

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', onChangeHandler);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('visibilitychange', onChangeHandler);
    };
}, []);
```

This event listener failed to trigger when navigating away from the page at all. It only triggered on actions like minimizing the browser and switching tabs which I don't want at all and when the page was refreshed.

**beforeunload event and `useBeforeUnload` hook**

Next, I tried the above with the `beforeunload` event but this event would only trigger on page refresh.

I then used the `useBeforeUnload` hook that React Router 6 added and had the same issue where only a page refresh would trigger the event.

```
useBeforeUnload(
    useCallback(() => {
        callMutation();
    }, []),
);
```

So in summary, wondering if there is any way for me to call out to my GraphQL API when a specific page is navigated away from in the cases of using the browser's back arrow, when the page is unmounted, and when the tab is closed. Thanks for any help/info!

Comment: There is no way to really call the backend when page is navigated away/closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unloading the page is different than unmounting a component because navigation occurred. You may very well need to apply different logic to handle the different ways a user goes "away from a page". When the page is reloaded or the tab/window is closed, any running Javascript is *immediately* quit. In other words, any unmounting `useEffect` hook cleanup functions won't run because ***nothing*** is running anymore; it's all terminated.

Example using the `window.beforeunload` event to handle a page reload, tab closing etc ***and*** also handling the component simply unmounting.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unloadCallback = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = ""; // * required for browser compatibility

    callMutation(); // call external function/effect

    return ""; // * required for browser compatibility
  };

  // listen for page unloading
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);

  // return cleanup function to cancel listener and call function
  // is simply unmounting
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);

    callMutation(); // call external function/effect
  };
}, []);
```